# simplest way to match a string pattern

Tags: javascript, regex, string

I have a list with string and want to sort any string that matches the following pattern:

```
a+[0-9]+framewall+[0-9]+
```

I.e., the string would be something like a3framewall21.

What is the easiest way of doing this in Javascript?

Thanks,

Comment: So, you have an array of strings, and you want to filter or extract to another array the values that match the pattern?

Comment: Take care that `framewall+` will match `framewallllll`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried the string.match method?

```
js> mystring='a3framewall21';
a3framewall21
js> mystring.match(/a\d+framewall\d+/);
a3framewall21
```

Comment: That would return me a list of strings. Is there a function that just returns whether the string matches the pattern, like false or true?

Comment: Since it returns null if there is no match, you can simply use this expression in a boolean context

Comment: `/a\d+framewall\d+/.test(str);`

Comment: @cxreg: *"you can simply use this expression in a boolean context"* -- No, **you cannot use it in a boolean context in javascript**. To do so, you must first cast it with `mystring.match(...)===null`. Otherwise you run into situations like `null==false -> false`. and `'true'.match(/true/)==true -> true`.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean.  null == false is not boolean context, it's a comparison to a specific value, that being false in this case, which is not the same.  null is boolean false.  if(string.match(/a\d+framewall\d+/)) works just fine

Comment: @ninjagecko: As @cxreg said, you can use it this way. `null` always evaluates to `false` and an array or (not empty) string to `true`. So it is perfectly fine to use `if(str.match(...))`.

Comment: @Felix: yes, I am aware, and I do not disagree on that point. =)

Comment: Best way to cast a boolean in JavaScript is `!!something`. The first bang instantly casts it to its opposing boolean value, the second converts it back to its 'real boolean value'.

Answer (score 2):

`/a\d+framewall\d+/.test(str);` – cwolves 8 mins ago

This is superior because it returns a boolean value. So you can write for example:

```
function doesItMatch(regex, query) {
    return regex.test(query);
}
```

Which will allow you to write things like this (which string.match(...) cannot do because the values are truthy and falsy):

```
doesItMatch(regex1,query)==doesItMatch(regex2,query)
```

Comment: Actually `if(str.match(/foo/))` will work perfectly fine since `.match` returns `null` (falsy) if no match is found and an array (truthy) if one is found and your 2nd example can be accomplished by double negating the match, e.g: `!!str.match(/.../)`.  Not saying that's a good pattern, just pointing it out :)